# function not being called after body onload

Tags: javascript, onload, lifecycle

Hello I have a Javascript function initMap(); I would like this function to be loaded via body onload="initMap();" After the page is loaded i can go into IE's debugger and write initMap(); in the console and it still says this function is undefined. I know there is some issue with the page lifecycle but im unsure what the problem exactly is. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 11,
    center: {
      lat: 33.923928,
      lng: -118.245153
    }
  });
  var trafficLayer = new google.maps.TrafficLayer();
  trafficLayer.setMap(map);
}
var fancy = document.createElement('script');
fancy.src = 'scripts/jquery-1.12.1.min.js';
fancy.type = 'text/javascript';
fancy.language = "javascript";
document.head.appendChild(fancy);
fancy.onload = function() {
  $.noConflict();
  initMap()
  SetSlideIntervals()
  jQuery.ajax({
    dataType: "json",
    url: "http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Traffic/Incidents/33.799323,-118.402795,34.045909,-118.086747?key=Aq1xeHo7y0F9fT24Yk4DlC5tEFmf_RiGLc4wj734BXZpevMgGM4uZNvk4sc3PEpD",
    data: "",
    success: function(WeatherObj) {
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Where and how are you loading your script into your HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using jQuery, why not just use the DOM-ready jQuery handler?

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>Test stuff</title>
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                $( document ).ready(function() {
                        console.log( "ready!" );
                        function initMap() {
                            // your code here
                        }

                        initMap();
                });
            </script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

You can see the full jQuery documentation for that function:
https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Answer (score 1):

Use this snippet:

```
window.onload = function () {
   //all your code goes here.
}
```

or use html5 defer right this:

```
<script src="code.js" defer></script>
```

Comment: I've tried putting everything in the window.onload event but unfortunantly initMap is never called. If I got to the debugger in IE I receive the error initMap() is undefined when typing this into the con sole manually.. I have noticed that when i add this page to compatble view settings it does work properly.

Comment: Im unsure what the defer does are you saying that instead of creating a javascript variable that is my jQuery i should just type defer in the script source?

Answer (score -1):

```
window.onload = function(){
function initMap() {
              var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                  zoom: 11,
                  center: { lat: 33.923928, lng: -118.245153 }
              });

              var trafficLayer = new google.maps.TrafficLayer();
              trafficLayer.setMap(map);
          }
          var fancy = document.createElement('script');
          fancy.src = 'scripts/jquery-1.12.1.min.js';
          fancy.type = 'text/javascript';
          fancy.language = "javascript";
          document.head.appendChild(fancy);
          fancy.onload = function () {
              $.noConflict();
              initMap()
              SetSlideIntervals()


              jQuery.ajax({
                  dataType: "json",
                  url: "http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Traffic/Incidents/33.799323,-118.402795,34.045909,-118.086747?key=Aq1xeHo7y0F9fT24Yk4DlC5tEFmf_RiGLc4wj734BXZpevMgGM4uZNvk4sc3PEpD",
                  data: "",
                  success: function (WeatherObj) {

                  }

              });

          }

    initMap();    
 }
```

Put everything within window.onload()

After everthing loaded you have to call to your function.

Comment: Nope. That just means the `initMap` function would only be available inside of the `window.onload` function. Plus, they're already adding a listener using `body onload="initMap()"`.